# How to print the Fibonacci sequence in one line using python?

Tags: python, list, parameter-passing, sequence

I just need to print the sequence in one line, how do I do that? Thanks to those who'll answer

```
n = input("Enter n: ")

def fib(n):
    cur = 1
    old = 1
    i = 1
    while (i < n):
        cur, old, i = cur+old, cur, i+1
    return cur

for i in range(10):
    print(fib(i))
```

Comment: You really want to recalculate the whole sequence for every item?

Comment: I need to display the sequence in one line but I don't know how..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a argument in `print()` function:

```
print(fib(i), end=" ")
```

Answer (score 2):

by default, the print function ends with a newline "/n" character

You can replace that with whatever character you want with the `end` keyword argument

e.g.

```
print(fib(i), end = " ")
```